# Json d3 access each object

Tags: d3.js

```
{
 "name": "Max",
 "value": 107,
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "Don",
   "value": 60,
   "children" [
     {"name": "CC", "value": 25},
     {"name": "Jim", "value": 35}
     ]
     },
  {
   "name": "David",
   "value": 47,
   "children": [
       {"name": "Jeff", "value": 32},
       {"name": "Buffy", "value": 15}
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
```

How can I access the inner most child name with d3?

I tried doing :

> .text(function (d) { return d.children ? null : d.name; });

But it didn't work....

When I do

> .text(function (d) { return d.name });

it only shows the name of the outer loop --> Don, David.

```
d3.json('flare.json', function (data) {

  var canvas = d3.select('p1')
             .append('svg')
             .attr('width', 800)
             .attr('height', 800)

  var color = d3.scale.category20c();

  var data1 = data.children;

  canvas.selectAll('text')
              .data(data1)
              .enter()
              .append('text')
                 .attr('x', function (d) { return 2; })
                 .attr('y', function (d, i) { return i * 15; })
                 .attr('fill', 'black')
                 .style('font-size', '12px')
                 .text(function (d) { return d.children ? null: d.name; })
```

Data I had before ↓ ↓

```
{
"name": "Don",
"value": 75,
"children" [
           {"name": "CC", "value": 25},
           {"name": "Jim", "value": 35}
   ]
}
```

When the data was in this single nested format, my code worked perfectly, but when I did double nest on it, it no longer works

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a recursive function for this --

```
function getNames(d) {
    return d.children ? d.children.map(getNames) : d.name;
}
```

This will return a nested list with the names of the elements that have no children.

Comment: Hey that works, but what I am trying to do is to append .text onto shapes. How can get the data so it comes up one by one, instead of a big chuck of name separated by commas

Comment: The names are returned as a nested list. Maybe you're printing the result and it automatically concatenates the entries?

Comment: Yes, i am printing out the results, but i want them to be printed out follow the attribute, 2 pixels to the right and 15 pix down for each additional i

Comment: Ok, so you would pass the array you get from `getNames` to `data` and then add elements in the usual manner.