# d3 json counting the most inner loop

Tags: d3.js

```
{
 "name": "Max",
 "value": 107,
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "Don",
   "value": 60,
   "children" [
     {"name": "CC", "value": 25},
     {"name": "Jim", "value": 35}
     ]
     },
  {
   "name": "David",
   "value": 47,
   "children": [
       {"name": "Jeff", "value": 32},
       {"name": "Buffy", "value": 15}
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
```

How do you count the children of the group?

```
data.children.length;
```

does not seem to work.
(data is set to equal the js)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? You most likely need a recursive function unless you always know the deepest depth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Json d3 access each object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409958/json-d3-access-each-object)

Comment: I am trying to find out the number of children in the nested loop whom themselves have no children. For example: CC, Jim, Jeff, Buffy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the number of leaves in a tree. You can recursively traverse the tree to do it:

```
getNumberOfLeaves = function (obj) {
    if (obj.children) {
        var res = 0; 
        obj.children.forEach(function(d){res+=getNumberOfLeaves(d)})
        return res
    }else {
        return 1
    }
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/PVhUn/